# How can I implement Full text search by using Prisma + PostgreSQL ? (I'm using Supabase as the database)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, prisma, database-schema, supabase

This is my schema file below

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["fullTextSearch","fullTextIndex"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Category {
  id            String @id @db.Uuid @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()"))
  name          String
  companions    Companion[]
}


model Companion {
  id            String @id @db.Uuid @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()"))
  userId        String
  userName      String
  src           String
  name          String @db.Text 
  description   String
  instruction   String @db.Text
  seed          String @db.Text

  createdAt     DateTime @default(dbgenerated("now()"))
  updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt

  category      Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId    String

  @@index([categoryId])
  @@fulltext([name])
}
```

Here I am unable to implement @@fulltext feature, showing Error parsing attribute "@@fulltext": Defining fulltext indexes is not [text](https://stackoverflow.com)supported with the current connector. please do let me know how can I do this as @@fulltext can be used with mySQL

Answer (score 3):

Prisma Client does not currently support using indexes to speed up full text search on postgresSQL. You can install MySQL Community Edition and change your provider to MySQL easily.

There is a link I think it might be helpful to you:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search

Answer (score 0):

...Prisma Client supports full-text search for PostgreSQL databases in versions 2.30.0 and later, and MySQL databases in versions 3.8.0 and late...

https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/full-text-search

Answer (score -3):

It's happening only with postgresSQL, if you change provider to mysql error gone.

Comment: but how can I change provider to mysql, I am using Supabase which uses postgreSQL